# Creating a delay between posting comments

Tags: php, comments, delay

Im adding a comment section to my forums and i want to add a delay, Maybe 30 seconds or so to stop people spamming along with a captcha .

Whats the best way to do this? Only way i can think is using cookies, any other suggestions?

Comment: SO is the only place where i saw such delay and captcha!

Comment: Cookies are definitively the wrong way as the can be deleted by the user/client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user post their comment, write the current timestamp in a session and add it additional 30 seconds:

```
$_SESSION['postedTime'] = time() + 30;
```

When you want to check if 30 seconds are passed, get the current timestamp and compare them: if the current timestamp is bigger then one in session, then 30 seconds are passed:

```
$timestamp = time();
if($timestamp > $_SESSION['postedTime'])
{
    // allow posting
}
else
{
    // decline
}
```

For more security, you could insert user's IP + post timestamp in the database.

Comment: When i put my code like this it kept saying declining, when i swapped the > for a < it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP sessions to do something like this, but not sure how 'fool' proof it is.

The idea would be do something:

```
if(isset($_POST['cmdComment'])){
  $_SESSION['comment_posted'] = time();
}
```

Then you could have a function say `checkTime()` which you could put inside there to subtract the session value from the time it is now. If the difference is `>= 30` seconds, then continue with the post and set the `$_SESSION['comment_posted']` to the new time, otherwise ignore the post request.

Answer (score 0):

1. When the comment is inserted in the database, make sure to keep track of the user and timestamp.
2. When the user goes to post again, check if the last comment he posted was 30seconds before.
3. Deal with this accordingly

Answer (score 0):

A forum usually has members, well atleast I don't know any that do not have it.

Now if you post a comment I assume you put that in a table called something like Comment with an ID, POST_ID, USER_ID, MESSAGE, POST_DATETIME

Atleast thats how I would do it.

Now you have the datetime when the user last commented on the a certain post. Now you can query your database whether he or she can comment again